# Multi-arguments python map

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have this scenario: I have a method some_method(x, y) that takes two arguments. The first argument is a list `temp_list` whilst the second argument is a list of dictionaries `list_of_dict`.

I have the following:

```
  def outer_method(self, list_of_dict):
    temp_list = []
    for x in list_of_dict:
      self.some_method(temp_list, x)
    return temp_list
```

But i want to know how i can use python's map function to make the code look more refined.

Comment: @kaya3 you should put your comments as an answer or suggested solution and i will pick it as the answer

Comment: Sure, I've done so.

Comment: Your code looks refined enough as it is.

Comment: The title to this question is misleading and should read 'Multi-arguments python map when modifying its inputs' or somesuch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `some_method` works by side-effects (i.e. it mutates the input `temp_list`), you should not use `map` for this; your `for` loop is the sensible way to write this code. `map` should not be used for side-effects, and using higher-order functions doesn't automatically mean your code is better.

That said, if `some_method` works by appending some elements to `temp_list` and doesn't change the rest of its contents, you could refactor so that `some_method` yields those elements instead of appending them. Then `outer_method` could be implemented like:

```py
    def outer_method(self, list_of_dict):
        return list(chain.from_iterable(map(self.some_method, list_of_dict)))
```

Where `some_method` takes a single dictionary as its argument, and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is imported from the `itertools` module.